# Wordpress change permalinks post in specyfic category

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I want to change permalinks posts in category /lekarz/subcategory

I want to delete a parent category **if** post in /lekarz/subcategory

Example:

domain.com/lekarz/ginekolog/post-name

I want

domain.com/ginekolog/post-name

Other permalinks posts unchanged.

Example

domain.com/blog/subcategory/subcategory2/post-name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Click on General => Permalinks
2. See what your current permalink settings are
3. Depending on your current settings, select a different permalink option ( IE: if you are set to Post name, select Default.
4. Click Save Changes
5. Now that your changes have saved, select the original Permalink setting
6. Click Save Changes
7. Check to see if your permalinks have corrected

Answer (score 0):

All url work ok
I want to get other url for specific posts in a category lekarz/subcategory/

Wordpress settings are ok